# Forcing .Net Core to use local javascript/lib files when publishing

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017

I'm writing a .Net Core Application in which I am using `bower` to keep track of my javascript dependencies.

I am using `bootstrap 3.3.7` and there is a pretty commonly known problem with bootstrap 3.3.7 which has to do with popovers/tooltips as seen [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21830)

I have modified my `bootstrap.js` file as described in the link above and I now want to use this modified `bootstrap.js` file for my publish when I publish my project on my web server.

I have changed the code in my `_Layout.cshtml` to use this file, but it seems as if my `wwwroot/` directory isn't published together with the rest of my project, and therefore it isn't utilizing my modified bootstrap file, which results in my page still getting an error and not displaying what I need it to. I might actually look like that when I publish, bower is used to download the library that I have defined in my `bower.json` file and package that with my publish.

I have tried removing bootstrap from that file, but to no avail. And I have even tried rolling back to `bootstrap 3.3.6`, but it seems as the popover functionality wasn't implemented in that version, and I therefore just got a bunch of other different errors.

## code snippet from _Layout.cshtml

```
@* Use local bootstrap due to bootstrap 3.3.7 error *@
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
@*<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
          asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
          asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal">
</script>*@
```

I assume the only solution is to force Visual Studio to publish my modified `bootstrap.js` file when I do a publish, but how do I do so? And if this isn't the case what other alternatives are there? I'm hoping that there is a solution to this problem.

As of right now the devs are not planning on fixing the problem as they are busy with boostrap v4, which is understandable, but that is not something I plan to tag along on just yet, so I need to use `bootstrap 3.3.7`.

Comment: How are you referencing your `js` file in `_Layout.cshtml`? Are you using `StaticFiles`?

Comment: I am referencing my `js` file in `_Layout.cshtml`. Please see my addition to my question.

Comment: I will look into `StaticFiles` to see if that can solve my problem. Thanks! :D